# unexpected 'NoneType' object is not iterable error when returning a tuple

Tags: python

I'm building a simple blackjack game and sometimes after a when either you want to stay, or when the dealer stays I get a 'NoneType'object is not iterable error. I believe that it is happening at the return of `True, total` in both the move() and dealer() functions, but can't see why this would be happening. I'm very new to python so I'm sure it's an easy fix.
Any help?

```
import random
import re

def make_deck(deck):
    deck.append("Clubs_Ace")
    deck.append("Clubs_2")
    deck.append("Clubs_3")
    deck.append("Clubs_4")
    deck.append("Clubs_5")
    deck.append("Clubs_6")
    deck.append("Clubs_7")
    deck.append("Clubs_8")
    deck.append("Clubs_9")
    deck.append("Clubs_10")
    deck.append("Clubs_Jack")
    deck.append("Clubs_Queen")
    deck.append("Clubs_King")
    deck.append("Spades_Ace")
    deck.append("Spades_2")
    deck.append("Spades_3")
    deck.append("Spades_4")
    deck.append("Spades_5")
    deck.append("Spades_6")
    deck.append("Spades_7")
    deck.append("Spades_8")
    deck.append("Spades_9")
    deck.append("Spades_10")
    deck.append("Spades_Jack")
    deck.append("Spades_Queen")
    deck.append("Spades_King")
    deck.append("Hearts_Ace")
    deck.append("Hearts_2")
    deck.append("Hearts_3")
    deck.append("Hearts_4")
    deck.append("Hearts_5")
    deck.append("Hearts_6")
    deck.append("Hearts_7")
    deck.append("Hearts_8")
    deck.append("Hearts_9")
    deck.append("Hearts_10")
    deck.append("Hearts_Jack")
    deck.append("Hearts_Queen")
    deck.append("Hearts_King")
    deck.append("Diamonds_Ace")
    deck.append("Diamonds_2")
    deck.append("Diamonds_3")
    deck.append("Diamonds_4")
    deck.append("Diamonds_5")
    deck.append("Diamonds_6")
    deck.append("Diamonds_7")
    deck.append("Diamonds_8")
    deck.append("Diamonds_9")
    deck.append("Diamonds_10")
    deck.append("Diamonds_Jack")
    deck.append("Diamonds_Queen")
    deck.append("Diamonds_King")
    return deck

def draw_card(deck):
    card=deck[len(deck)-1]
    deck.remove(card)
    return card

def shuffle_deck(deck):
    shuffled_deck=random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def cardval(card,total):
    if "2" in card or "3" in card or "4" in card or "5" in card or "6" in card or "7" in card or "8" in card or "9" in card or "10" in card:
        return int(re.findall("\d+",card)[0])
    elif "Jack" in card or "Queen" in card or "King" in card:
        return 10
    elif "Ace" in card:
        if total <= 10:
            return 11
        else:
            return 1


def deal(deck):
    print("Your cards:")
    draw1=draw_card(deck)
    draw2=draw_card(deck)
    total=0
    dealersTotal=0
    total=cardval(draw1,total)
    total+=(cardval(draw2,total))
    print(draw1,draw2," Total:",total,"\n")
    print("Dealers cards:")
    draw3=draw_card(deck)
    dealersTotal+=cardval(draw3,dealersTotal)
    print(draw3,"   face_down_card  Dealers Total:",dealersTotal)
    face_down=draw_card(deck)
    dealersTotal+=cardval(face_down,dealersTotal)
    return total, dealersTotal,face_down;

def move(total,deck):
    choice = input("Would you like to hit or stay? (h to hit, s to stay)")
    if choice is 'h':
        draw=draw_card(deck)
        total+=cardval(draw,total)
        print(draw,"  Total:",total,"\n")
        if total > 21:
            print('bust')
            return False, total
        else: move(total,deck)
    elif choice is 's':
        return True, total

def dealer(dealersTotal,deck):
    if dealersTotal < 17:
        draw=draw_card(deck)
        dealersTotal+=cardval(draw,dealersTotal)
        print("\nDealer hits ",draw,"dealers Total ",dealersTotal)
        if dealersTotal > 21:
            print("Dealer bust, you win!")
            return True,dealersTotal
        elif dealersTotal in range(17,21):
            return False,dealersTotal
        elif dealersTotal < 17:
            dealer(dealersTotal,deck)

def again():
    again=input("Would you like to play again? (y for yes, n for no):")
    if again is 'y':
        print("\n\n\n")
        driver()
    elif again is 'n':
        print("Thanks for playing")


def driver():    
    deck=[]
    shuffled_deck=[51]
    total=0
    dealersTotal=0
    deck=make_deck(deck) 
    shuffled_deck=shuffle_deck(deck)
    total, dealersTotal, face_down=deal(shuffled_deck)
    player_move,total=move(total,shuffled_deck)
    if player_move is False:
        again()
    elif player_move is True:
        result,dealersTotal=dealer(dealersTotal,shuffled_deck)
        if result is False:
            again()
        elif result is True:
            print("Your total:",total,"Dealers total:",dealersTotal)
            if total > dealersTotal:
                print("\nYou win!\n")
                again()
            elif dealersTotal > total:
                print("\nYou loose :(\n")
                again()

driver()
```

Comment: Why do you think that returning a tuple is the cause of the error?

Comment: The error is thrown when I type 's' after hitting and it's thrown when the dealer has between a 17 and 21. Maybe it's not the return, if it is not then it's the assignment from the call in the driver function.

Comment: Close; it's actually the *lack* of a return that causes a problem.  In other words, the `dealer` and `move` functions have some branches that aren't returning anything.  If you don't return anything, the implicit return value is `None` which can cause the error you describe.

Comment: Hmmm I thought that the recursive call would guarantee that one of the two returns were used, could you explain why that isn't true?

Comment: When the inner recursive call returns, control will resume where you left off in the outer calling function.  So you still have to return a value from that one.  In other words, `return` will only hand its return value to the containing "layer" of the recursion; you have to keep `return`ing those inner values all the way up the call stack.  The simple solution in this case is to just `return move(total,deck)` and `return dealer(dealersTotal,deck)`.

Comment: The ever elusive stack, thank you so much for a great explanation, your fix works perfectly!